# Why does my heat pump condenser outlet make a single pass through the evaporator before the expansion valve?

Tags: thermodynamics, hvac

I'm hoping to modify a hot water heat pump to capture both the hot and cold side. I'd work with an HVAC shop to make the modification but want to understand the circuit. It's not the simplest of units in that it includes an economizer circuit, but the standard building blocks are there: compressor, condenser (a shell-and-tube heat exchanger for the hot-water), expansion valve, and evaporator fan coil.

What's strange to me is that the refrigerant path from the condenser output flows through a tiny portion of the evaporator - a single pass of the bottom-most tubes (1 set out of about 40 or so) - before continuing to the filter-drier and then the main flow is on through the economizer heat exchanger, the main expansion valve, and finally the main portion of the evaporator (the other ~39 sets of tubes) (a portion is diverted after the filter-drier for economizer / vapor injector operation).

I'm curious why this might have been done - seems like it's just a waste of heat. The pipe leading there is even insulated until it reaches the fan-coil - and later again as it reaches the economizer heat exchanger.

Other details which probably aren't relevant, but just in case: the refrigerant is 134a, the max water temp is ~80C, and the unit has a reversing valve so it should be usable as a chiller (haven't tried) but the filter-drier is unidirectional mounted for water heating.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Purely a guess, but maybe to prevent condensate from freezing and plugging the condensate drain.

Comment: Interesting idea - the unit is open under the coil rather than having a condensate pan and drainage pipe - but perhaps it generally reduces the chances of frost forming in cold conditions. Doesn't seem likely to be very effective though - I'd guess most of that heat is blown away before it gets a chance to melt much - although perhaps if there's enough frost to block airflow then more heat could rise. I suppose between cycles the heat would help.